# Preventing programs from being blocked by Norton

Tags: norton

I wrote a C# text editor and gave it to a user recently.

Upon running the software, Norton AV immediately deleted it. The error report he sent me indicated that it was doing "suspicious operations".

I was simply writing to a text file. :o

Does anyone have any information about what is likely to trip the heuristics in this sort of situation?

Comment: My first thought is, where was it writing to a text file? Perhaps Norton did not like a location it was trying to put something, or the name of the file(s), etc.

Comment: Another reason to hate anti-viruses!

Comment: What's the program do on startup? Anything unusual? Interesting question...

Comment: I had similar problem with Norton and .pl scripts. Norton kept removing files recognizing them as "harmful exploits". Solved by removing Norton and installing Nod32 or Avira (can't remember witch one). Problem gone!